# What is this early biplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

This is a 1910-1920 biplane that landed at Oregon Agricultural College. now Oregon State University. I've cropped out some of the people and horses. Thank you[[image]]

Comment: What’s the source of the picture?

Comment: It seems like it's a picture taken of an image. 
Would it be possible to get a higher-resolution picture?
That might help in identifying characterizing features

Comment: This is original I found on internet in 2018. I don't remember where. https://www.97330.com/biplane_CorvallisFirstAirplane_2.jpg

Comment: I put the original photo into the question instead of the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.aerofiles.com/_ga.html) is it. Similarities are: two bay strut braced biplane with upper single wing one extra bay wider than lower wing, inner struts just outside fuselage, overwing brace above outermost strut, visible structure under upper wing, same prop shape, very short rudder and skid landing gear with double wheels.

Your photo seems to have a different landing gear, a single center set with a second set of wheels at the back of the skids, which looks here like they just drag on the ground. This also appeared on floats.

[image]

> Fowler-Gage NASM restoration with OX-5 (NASM)

> 1912 = 1pOB; 60-80hp Hall-Scott A-2/-3; span: (upper) 41'0" to 42'8" (lower) 30'0" v: 60. POP: 4 or 5 for exhibition pilots Robert Fowler (aka Fowler-Gage with 80hp Hall-Scott A-3, occasionally on floats), Roy Francis, Phil Parmalee, and J Clifford Turpin. Design carried forward to the twin-prop Patterson-Francis. The Fowler-Gage was donated to Smithsonian in 1950 and restored for display by NASM in 1988.

Here is another pic showing the [single central float](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/air-space-magazine/aviation-journalists-accused-spies-180973604/).

[image: Fowler Gage with single central float]

Comment: While the wings are similar, the original photo (I suggest using the link in the comments) has a prominent bracing from the engine to the central wheel / skid. Further, the Fowler Gage has triplane winglets, which I think would be visible on the photo despite its poor quality; and has a distinctive engine cylinder arrangement which doesn't appear to match on the photo either. Finally, there was a fuel tank mounted on top of the wing, which also isn't present. On balance I don't think it's a Fowler Gage.

Comment: @PartyArk It may not be the exact year, but I think you are wrong on the engine. Both aircraft have shiny V cylinders which can be seen in both photos. Landing gears are interchangeable and do not change the model of aircraft. A C180 on floats is still a C180. A single gear didn't work well and eventually got eliminated but if a C180 had a single skid gear, it would still be a C180.

Comment: I take your point, but the nature of the prominent chin on the Fowler Gage, and the way it lifts the engine / cylinders close to the top wing, and hence puts the prop above the line of the top of the fuselage just aren't replicated in the aircraft in the picture. In all I'd say different engine, missing winglets, missing fuel tank and unique undercarriage all point to a different a/c.